# What’s the energy required to traverse through dimensions

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space-constructs, dimensions

Say in the future, humanity has developed technology to the point that it allows them to traverse through other universe, each universe having something either drastically different or not so different from our own universe.

But let’s say that humanity has the same somewhat problem here on earth, overpopulation, Without getting into the very specifics of how that would be possible, the humans decide that instead of just trying to colonize other universe, they can simply try to colonize a different dimension.

The humans have countless resources that will allow them to make the machine, the only problem is, is that they are trying to figure out just how much energy it would require for them to operate such a machine.

How much energy would be required to simply traverse into another dimension?

Comment: It’s 2.74 milliPlots, where a Plot is the unit for measuring Applied Handwavium. 
Genuinely. The answer here is ‘however much or little makes sense for your story’, since you’re the one inventing the tech.

Comment: I want to improve on this question, however, And I also want to make it sound more like a question instead of some missing plot device, can you give me some advice on how to do so.

Comment: How far away is the other universe? Is there such a thing as interversal space, or interversal medium? Or does every universe touch at least one other, and you just need a 10D ramp? The standard model doesn't really have answers to these, though M Theory, the Many Worlds Interpretation, etc sorta gesture thatword. How I'd do it would require some kinda exotic matter, but even then, the energy required would be based on the details. Or, to put it another way, how does a letter on page 1 move to page 21? Probably by crawling into the binding.

Comment: It isn't a problem that requires you to merely throw energy at it, or highly energetic events like gamma ray bursts would have already triggered it. As such, the answer is either "_more energy than has ever been released in a natural event_" or "_it doesn't matter how much energy is required, only that you have the right handwavium_". I suspect that the latter is what you're after.

Comment: The question severely lacks a `science-based` explanation of what *another dimension* is. Read @JoeBloggs's comment carefully.

Answer (score 2):

**It can be what you need it to be.**

Energy of activation is a useful concept.

[image: energy of activation]

Suppose I embark on dimensional travel, across town.  I am riding my dirt bike.  I start on the left of the graph.  I must input a lot of energy to climb that hump.  I get it all back and more on descending to the other side.  A different ride might have a lower hump, or no hump and a nice coast all the way, or I do not get back all the energy I put in because I end up at a higher altitude than when I started.  The energy required for real dimensional travel on a dirt bike depends on the energy states of start, finish and what is between.

The same for funky types of dimensional travel.  You might have an energy of activation you need to pay into depending on how your dimensions are separated.  Or it might not cost energy to transition dimensions if you open the portal correctly - you can coast.   In some stories stuff falling into our dimension from another one can be used to generate energy on this side.  You can make it what works.